# Select-Tag Helper .NET Core to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I have tried to submit tag-select with 'submit' button and it worked properly but how about without submit button ?

I want to send the value of tag-select directly to controller every time it changes without javascript. Is that possible ?

```
@model MyViewModel
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create">
    <select asp-for="EmployeeId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.EmployeesList,"Id","FullName"))">
        <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>
</form>


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(MyViewModel model)
{
    //check model.EmployeeId 
    //to do : Save and redirect
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a clear description of the problem, preferrably with a code sample. I find it really hard to follow what you want to say.

Comment: @Sefe, I run out battrey. It has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select asp-for="EmployeeId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.EmployeesList,"Id","FullName"))" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    ...
</select>
```