# Select Tag Helper get value and text

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I just read this [Select Tag Helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc), how to use tag helper and previously I asked about **[onchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217867/select-tag-helper-net-core-to-controller)** for select tag helper.

But this time, I need to get the **text** of the select tag helper.
This is my model:

```
public class Paid__Period {
    [Key]
    public Int16 ID_Period { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view:

```
<select asp-for="Period" class="form-control input-sm"                        
    asp-items="@(new SelectList (@ViewBag.Period, "ID_Period", "Period"))" onchange="this.form.submit()">
</select>
```

When it rendered into HTML, it becomes

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="Period" name="Period">
   <option value="0">- Choose Period -</option>
   <option value="1">2016 - 1 (Jan - Jun)</option>
   <option value="2">2017 - 1 (Jan - Jun)</option>
   <option value="3">2017 - 2 (Jul - Dec)</option>
   <option value="4">2018 - 1 (Jan - Jun)</option>
   <option value="5">2018 - 2 (Jul - Dec)</option>
   <option value="6">2019 - 1 (Jan - Jun)</option>
   <option value="7">2019 - 2 (Jul - Dec)</option>
   <option value="8">2020 - 1 (Jan - Jun)</option>
</select>
```

Till here, everything works well. But I need return value from view to action controller every time selected are ID_Period and Period: '**2020 - 1 (Jan - Jun)**'.
How to do this?

I just prepare my action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Paid_Tuition (Paid_Period period) {
}
```

but Paid_Period is always null.
Any suggestion to solve my problem above?

Comment: `but Paid_Period is always null. `-Show me the javascript code that you have already tried.

Comment: Why you're putting `onchange="this.form.submit()"` to submit form after changing selected value? You need to store selected text value inside hidden field and use `select asp-for="ID_Period"` instead.

Comment: @TanvirArjel, I dont use any javascript.

Comment: @Daleman Is `Paid_Tuition (Paid_Period period)`  the post method for your form?

Comment: @TanvirArjel, yes. Paid_Tuition is the action method.

Comment: @Daleman Is your form containing more other fields than `Period` select list?

Comment: @Daleman What is the purpose of using `onchange="this.form.submit()"` in period select list tag?

Comment: @TanvirArjel, onchange is to trigger if I select different value

Comment: Okay! On that change event what you are actually doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188034/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-daleman).

Comment: `select asp-for="Period"` seem wrong from the start. You should use the ID property to hold integer value e.g. `select asp-for="ID_Period"` and get selected option text from selected value, then submit the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another tag helper (e.g. hidden field) bound to `string` property of your viewmodel to pass text option from selected value together with the `<select>` element itself:

```
<select asp-for="ID_Period" class="form-control input-sm"                        
    asp-items="@(new SelectList (@ViewBag.Period, "ID_Period", "Period"))" onchange="onSelectedIndexChanged(this)">
</select>
<input asp-for="Period" type="hidden" />
```

Then you can retrieve selected text option using JS function bound to `onchange` event:

```js
function onSelectedIndexChanged(value)
{
    var textValue = value.options[value.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('Period').value = textValue;

    // if you want to submit the form, uncomment this line below
    // document.getElementById('yourformId').submit();
}
```

Or if you're using jQuery then you could remove `onchange` event attribute and handle `change` event instead to assign value into hidden field:

```js
$('#ID_Period').change(function () {
    var textValue = $('#ID_Period option:selected').text();
    $('#Period').val(textValue);

    // if you want to submit the form, uncomment this line below
    // $('form').submit();
});
```

**Note:**

It's more recommended to trigger form submit using a button rather than `<select>` element's `change` event.

Comment: I got your point. By adding hidden element for textvalue and triggering 'change' to handle with javascript then submit the form.

Comment: `.value` only returns one selected item. I am using multi select tag helper with "multiple" keyword. how can I retrieve full list of selected items?

Answer (score 0):

> but Paid_Period is always null.

That's because your're posting an int and try to bind that int value to an instance `Paid__Period`.

Let's inspect your rendered HTML :

```
<form ... >
    ...

    <select class="form-control input-sm" onchange="this.form.submit()" id="Period" name="Period">
       <option value="0">- Choose Period -</option>
       <option value="1">2016 - 1 (Jan - Jun)</option>
       <option value="2">2017 - 1 (Jan - Jun)</option>
       <option value="3">2017 - 2 (Jul - Dec)</option>
       <option value="4">2018 - 1 (Jan - Jun)</option>
       <option value="5">2018 - 2 (Jul - Dec)</option>
       <option value="6">2019 - 1 (Jan - Jun)</option>
       <option value="7">2019 - 2 (Jul - Dec)</option>
       <option value="8">2020 - 1 (Jan - Jun)</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

When you select the "2020 -1 (Jan - Jun)", the payload sent to server is (assuming you're using a `content-type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ):

```
...&Period=7&...
```

But your action method is treating `period` as an instance of `Paid_Period` instead of an int :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Paid_Tuition (Paid_Period period) 
{
}
```

**How to solve**

change your action method to accept an int `period`, and construct an instance of `Paid_Period` according to the int period Id.

Comment: how to do that ? I mean I need the text (2020 -1 (Jan - Jun)) instead the index.

Comment: @Daleman Since you've constructed a selectlist by `asp-items="@(new SelectList (@ViewBag.Period, "ID_Period", "Period"))" `, there must be a Period list.  let's call it `Periods`. to convert a int of `ID_Period` to `Paid__Period`, simply call `Periods.Where(p => p.ID_Period).FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @Daleman or if you would like to accept a parameter of `Paid_Period` type, you could create a custom model binder to cast an int to an instance of that type.